# java multi-thread (two synchronized methods in one class)

Tags: java, multithreading

I implemented the class below and get this output:

```
dsfs2000  
2000  
b = 1000;
```

I am wondering why it is not:

```
b = 1000;  
dsfs2000  
2000
```

Since `t.start()` will call `m1()` first and `m2()` should wait until `m1()` finishes, why `m2()` actually gets the lock first?

```
public class TT implements Runnable {
    int b = 100;

    public synchronized void m1() throws Exception{
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        b = 1000;
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
    }

    public synchronized void m2() throws Exception {

        Thread.sleep(2500);
        b = 2000;
        System.out.println("dsfs" + b);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            m1();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TT tt = new TT();
        Thread t = new Thread(tt);

        t.start();
        tt.m2();

        System.out.println(tt.b);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are calling t.start() which will inturn call run() method of the thread. In run() method you are calling m1(). Since threads executes parallely, you are calling m2() on the object directly so it executes first and then m1(). You can predict the thread starting behaviour. If want to verify the delay put the sysout.currentTimemilliseconds() in between the calls.

Comment: Try adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in between `t.start()` and `tt.m2()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
    t.start();  // has to go through the overhead of creating a Thread and calling back its `run`

    tt.m2();   // just calling a method on a already created Object, which is really fast
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `m1()` method add `notify();` at end, and in your `m2()` add `wait();` at the first, then it will be OK.

It is the full code: I have changed two places.Which is comment as `// here`

```
public class TT implements Runnable {
    int b = 100;

    public synchronized void m1() throws Exception{
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        b = 1000;
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
        notify(); // here
    }

    public synchronized void m2() throws Exception {
        wait(); // here
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        b = 2000;
        System.out.println("dsfs" + b);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            m1();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TT tt = new TT();
        Thread t = new Thread(tt);

        t.start();
        tt.m2();

        System.out.println(tt.b);
    }
}
```

And it is the output as you want:

```
b = 1000
dsfs2000
2000
```

**Explain:** `m2()` will wait until `m1()` finishes the job and notify the `m2();`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: your `main` method is executed in the main thread of your application. When calling `t.start();` you ask the JVM to make up a new thread and execute the `Runable`. This happens concurrently and it also takes some time. Calling the start method does not stop your main thread from continuing code execution. Due to this the `tt.m2()` is called. At the moment the JVM has created a new thread an stars executing the `runnable`, the `sysouts` of the `runnable` are printed out. To visualize this behavior. you could add the current time to you `system.out.print`.